# Correcting capture time in image files

Tags: bash, filesystems

I would like to make a list of pics inside a directory and check if they have capture time or not. If not, I would like to add a capture time as the minimum of modification date, creation date...

Is there any command for reading and assigning capture date to image files using bash commands?

Comment: Not built into bash, no. Available for your operating system, quite possibly yes -- see ImageMagick, or its newer incarnation GraphicsMagick.

Comment: Very few commands (relatively speaking) are actually "bash commands" -- almost everything you run (even `ls`!) is not a bash command but a UNIX command, which would work perfectly well with any other shell or no shell at all.

Comment: GraphicsMagick's `gm identify -debug all "$your_image_file_here"`, in particular, emits the metadata it's able to decode; you'd want to look at its output for your particular images to know if it contains what you need for their format.

Comment: BTW, standard UNIX systems don't track creation date -- what they call `ctime` is actually *metadata change* time, not *creation* time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jhead` for this. In the basic form, you run

```
jhead file.jpg

File size    : 1926198 bytes
File date    : 2014:03:01 11:59:27    
Camera make  : Apple
Camera model : iPhone 5
Date/Time    : 2014:03:01 11:59:27
```

And you can see it gives you the time and date the photo was shot.

If that is not present, you can use the following to create an EXIF section and set the date/time to the filesystem time of the file:

```
jhead -mkexif image.jpg

jhead image.jpg
File size    : 1926198 bytes
File date    : 2014:09:21 18:46:11
Camera make  : Apple
Camera model : iPhone 5
Date/Time    : 2014:09:21 18:46:11
```

Or alternatively, use the following to set the date/time to that specified on the command line:

```
jhead -dsyyyy:mm:dd file.jpg
```

For example:

```
jhead -ds2014:01:02 IMG_1594.JPG 

jhead IMG_1594.JPG 
File size    : 1926198 bytes
File date    : 2014:09:21 18:46:11
Camera make  : Apple
Camera model : iPhone 5
Date/Time    : 2014:01:02 18:46:11     <-------
```

Putting it all together, you get this:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob                                # Do nothing if no files present
shopt -s nocaseglob                              # Match upper and lower case jpg/JPG
for f in *.jpg; do                               # Loop through all files
    jhead "$f" | grep "^Date/Time"               # Check if date and time present
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then                        # If set,
        echo File: $f - Date/Time already set    # ... do nothing
    else
        echo File: $f - Setting Date/Time as per filesystem
        jhead -mkexif "$f"                       # ... else create an EXIF section
    fi
done
```

Before running this, please make a BACKUP!!!!!